# Adobe flash player 32 game performance is strange

Tags: performance, flash, adobe-flash

So I don't know if this question belongs here, but I will ask it anyway.

So this flash game is a .exe file and can only be played in Adobe flash player 32. This game is locked at 30 fps. (There is a .swf file.)

In idle on 1080p with low-quality settings, the game uses about 22% of my CPU The game gives me a steady 30fps.

In actual gameplay with the same settings. I still get a steady 30 fps. about 30% CPU

changing the quality settings to medium gives me this:

In idle, CPU 29%, I get 30 fps with dips to 25 fps.

gameplay, CPU 40%, I get around 15 fps.

Why is this happening? My CPU is a i7-7700HQ. What can I do to get a better framerate?

Comment: This is one of the many reasons Adobe Flash has been put in the bin...

Comment: "Why is this happening?" - You would have to ask the author of the game in question.  With Adobe Flash being unsupported in every modern supported browser and OS the performance problem might be difficult to solve.

Comment: What do you actually mean by "in idle" and "in actual gameplay". You use the exact same terms to prefix completely different results without actually telling us anything about what is different between those different results. Is it different areas of the game? Have you pulled out the power supply of you laptop? What *exactly* are you doing?

Comment: The obvious answer is your machine can't keep up. Put it on high quality & watch it perform even worse. This is a no-fix situation. Neither the game nor Flash will ever be updated, & in fact you must have some very old version for it not to have automatically disabled itself, so you're probably on an out of date OS too..

Comment: @Mokubai Yeah I should clarify that Idle means no loading of sprites every time the character does anything a sprite is loaded in which ups my CPU usage. And actual gameplay means constantly loading in sprites.

Comment: @Tetsujin So my windows 10 version is 2004 also I play this flash game offline in the standalone player from adobe

Comment: And that brings up yet more questions. What do you mean by "loading in"? Typically `swf` games came in a single monolithic file that is loaded entirely in one go at the start, there is no real "loading" after that. Do you mean that the game is showing and calculating more sprites, or that it is actually fetching and downloading more game assets? Showing more stuff does generally mean more scripts and so on are running and a poorly coded program (the game) running within another poorly coded program (flash) is just a recipe for things running poorly full stop. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that it's showing and calculating more sprites. the game has way too many sprites, like I decompiled the game jpexs-decompiler it has more than 1000 sprites, it also has a lot of action scripts (dunno which version) with more dan 10000 lines of code. but I start to think that I can't really do anything about this problem.